# Custom << method

Tags: ruby

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end

  def changed_callback
    puts "Bar has been changed!"
  end

  def bar
    @bar
  end

  def bar=(a)
    @bar = a
    self.changed_callback() # (hence why this doesn't just use attr_accessor)
  end

  def bar<<(a)
    @bar.push(a)
    self.changed_callback()
  end
end

f = Foo.new()
f.bar = [1,2,3]
  => "Bar has been changed!"
f.bar << 4
  => "Bar has been changed!"
puts f.bar.inspect
  => [1,2,3,4]
```

Is anything like that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll need to make `bar` return something else than a simple array, else how would you catch e.g `x=f.bar` followed later by `x<<4`?  So `bar` should return a subclass of array with a reference to the owning object and override `<<` to call the `changed_callback` method on the owner (but `x=f.bar; f.bar=[]; x<<4` becomes even trickier to handle if you _don't_ want the callback in that case -- `f` must know about all the `x`s it has ever handed out and "deactivate" them when a new `bar` is set, or `changed_callback` must accept the caller as an arg so `f` can check, or...

Comment: Ah! For some reason I was thinking attr_accessor just created a bar<< method like it does for bar=, but if that's not the case then you're spot on, it'll have subclass Array. Thanks! (want to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?)

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta.

Comment: @Victor: Like it, committed! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to somehow extend the object returned by `Foo#bar` with an appropriate `#<<` method. Something like this, maybe?

```
class Foo
  module ArrayProxy
    def <<(other)
      @__foo__.changed_callback
      super
    end
  end

  def initialize
    @bar = []
  end

  def changed_callback
    puts 'Bar has been changed!'
  end

  def bar
    return @bar if @bar.is_a?(ArrayProxy)
    @bar.tap {|bar| bar.extend(ArrayProxy).instance_variable_set(:@__foo__, self) }
  end

  def bar=(a)
    @bar = a
    changed_callback # (hence why this doesn't just use attr_accessor)
  end

end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = [1,2,3]
#  "Bar has been changed!"
f.bar << 4
#  "Bar has been changed!"
puts f.bar.inspect
#  => [1,2,3,4]
```